# after installing wpml my site loaded twice

Tags: performance, .htaccess, wpml

i've installed wpml on my wp site and the load speed is slow because the site is loaded twice as you can see here: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/b1sJnW/www.lasit.it

my .htaccess is this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the "browser language redirect" option enabled in WPML settings? If I recall correctly, it uses JavaScript to accomplish this, and therefore has to wait until the page is fully loaded before executing the redirect. I had a similar problem with my own website and ended up writing my own custom PHP function to accomplish the same functionality without the double page load.

Comment: Could you provide some more specifics and present the solution you came up with. It'd certainly help lots of people who experience the same problem. Thanks!